# CSS changing background color website

Tags: css, colors, background

ive been watching a tutorial that has told me to change the background color of a webpage by using:

```
body {background-color:red;}
```

however when i try and load the page in google chrome the background remains white?

This is my full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>              <!--Document START-->
    <head>              <!--Head START-->
        <title>Page Title</title>   
        <style type="text/css">                 <!--CSS START-->            
            body {  background-color:red }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>                          <!--Body START-->
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: works for me as it should : http://jsbin.com/azajen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you have an html comment within your css.

```
<style type="text/css">                 <!--CSS START-->
```

Remove the `<!--CSS START-->` and it will work fine.

If you want to add comments within css then you can use `/*  */`, e.g:

```
<style type="text/css">
/* CSS START */
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
body {  background-color:red; }
```

(You forgot the ; after "red")

Answer (score 0):

This works for you.

```
 body {
          background:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh yes, the problem is you have a html comment in the css, so it will not work after:  –